# Writing to Firestore exactly the same data object as in database's document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Does setting the same data that already exists in a Firestore db document with the following code counts as a write operation or is it optimised for this use case?

`await setDoc(refDoc, { the_same_data, as_in_refDoc })`

Comment: This is less a question about programming as it is a question about Firebase billing. I'd err on the pessimistic side and assume it counts as a new write. Of course, you could always do a test and check your usage statistics

Comment: I couldn't find this information easily and it's actually quite interesting and should be easily found. I suppose it could be optimised (if it's not already) by making a comparison with the local data before doing an actual write operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setDoc()` counts as a write regardless of the existence of any existing document and regardless of the contents of any existing document. It does *not* read the document before writing it to ensure that it does not redundantly write data; it *overwrites* any existing document at that location regardless of its contents.

This is documented in [Understand Cloud Firestore billing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations):

> You are charged for each document read, write, and delete that you perform with Cloud Firestore.
>
> Charges for writes and deletes are straightforward. For writes, each `set` or `update` operation counts as a single write.

The obvious indicator for this is that calling `set()` with redundant data still updates metadata on the document that you don't normally see, like timestamp data. Data is still written even if you haven't changed any fields in the document.